# NullPointerException in onCreate, can't seem to find the cause after debugging

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm fairly new to Android programming and have been searching around for some pointers to fix this problem, but I can't seem to get the exact problem down.

I guess I just need some pointers why and where it's throwing a NullPointerException so I can trace it myself in the future.

Some pieces of the related code:

```
   private static final long TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;
    private static final long TEN_SECONDS = 10000;
    private static final float TEN_METERS = 10;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "Locally";
    private static LocationManager locMan;
    Button StopButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Attempting to start service",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        startService(new Intent(LocallyActivity.this, LocallyService.class));

        StopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        double lat = 0;
        double longi = 0;
        TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Criteria crit = new Criteria();
        String strLoc = locMan.getBestProvider(crit, true);
        Location lastKnown = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(strLoc);
        if (lastKnown != null) {
            lat = lastKnown.getLatitude();
            longi = lastKnown.getLongitude();
            long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            long lastTime = lastKnown.getTime();
            long difference = tsLong - lastTime;

            Time time = new Time();
            time.set(Long.valueOf(lastTime));
            t.setText("" + lat + ", " + longi + " (" + strLoc + ", time: "
                    + time.hour + " " + time.minute + ")");

            Object networkLocation = requestUpdatesFromProvider(strLoc, 32);
        } else {
            t.setText("No last location from " + strLoc);
        }
    }

    private Location requestUpdatesFromProvider(final String provider,
            final int errorResId) {
        Location location = null;
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, provider);
        if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
            locMan.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TEN_SECONDS, TEN_METERS,
                    listener);
            location = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, errorResId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return location;

    }
```

And the error trace:

```
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start         activity ComponentInfo{com.somnu.locally/com.somnu.locally.LocallyActivity}:     java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at com.somnu.locally.LocallyActivity.requestUpdatesFromProvider(LocallyActivity.java:67)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at com.somnu.locally.LocallyActivity.onCreate(LocallyActivity.java:57)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
07-30 12:41:12.644: E/AndroidRuntime(20697):    ... 11 more
```

Line 67 is:

```
if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {
```

Comment: And which line is (LocallyActivity.java:67)?

Comment: have you added LocallyActivity in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: the line no which giving exception is  at com.somnu.locally.LocallyActivity.requestUpdatesFromProvider(LocallyActivity.java:67) can you highlight and post that line in your code

Comment: Line 67 is:

    if (locMan.isProviderEnabled(provider)) {

I've outputted provider and that points to "network", which is expected. locMan has been used to get the input of provider (see the onCreate function). Could it be that locMan isn't made available through the entire class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think `locMan is null so NPE...`

Use

```
locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

**instead of**

```
LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I will edit this and see if it has any effects, but I've tried outputting some strings from locMan and they work just fine. So I'm guessing that is not the problem.

Comment: It actually fixed my problem. But I have no idea why it didn't work like I wrote it before...